# how can i change format of matrix

Tags: matrices

I have a Matrix let we call it A Matrix, A[10*10] nodes and this matrix Aij=Aji as you see.
How can i can create from this matrix a matrix when a node connect another node randomly and it will be done for all nodes but for examle if x node connected y node y node will not connect x again

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&1&1&0&1&1&0&0 \\
1&0& 0& 1& 1& 0& 1& 1& 0& 0 \\
0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 1& 0& 1& 1& 1 \\
1& 1& 1& 0& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
1& 1& 1& 1& 0& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0& 0& 1& 1& 1& 0& 0& 1& 1& 1 \\
1& 1& 0& 1& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0 \\
1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 0& 1& 1 \\
0& 0& 1& 1& 1& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1 \\
0& 0& 1& 1& 1& 1& 0& 1& 1& 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Could it be that this is an adjacency matrix of an undirected graph and you want to have a matrix where all edges are given random orientation? Note that in other cases talking about nodes and connecting makes little sense.

Comment: yes this is an Adj matrix of an undirected grafh and i want convert Adj matrix of directed grafh

Comment: here is my code clear;
  rand('state', 5);
  numOfNodes = 10; 
  envSize=1;        
  txRange = 0.8;     
  global xLocation;   
  global yLocation;   
  xLocation = rand(numOfNodes,1) * envSize;
  yLocation = rand(numOfNodes,1) * envSize;
distMatrix = zeros(numOfNodes,numOfNodes);
for i=1:numOfNodes
   for j=1:numOfNodes
      distMatrix(i,j)=sqrt((xLocation(i)-xLocation(j))^2 + (yLocation(i)-yLocation(j))^2); 
   end
end
global A;
A = ( distMatrix < txRange); 
figure(1);
plot(xLocation, yLocation, '.');
return;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an adjacency matrix $A_{ij} = 1$ means *"there is an edge from node $i$ to node $j$"*. Adjacency matrix of a directed graph (without cycles of length $2$) will have $A_{ij} = 0$ or $A_{ji} = 0$. A way to enforce it is

```
for i = 1:numOfNodes
    for j = i+1:numOfNodes
        if(randomBoolean) A[i][j] = 0
        else A[j][i] = 0
```

Note that iteration goes through all pairs $i, j$ such that $i < j$. This ensures that a pair will only be oriented once.

Comment: If it better fits the problem, you can ignore randomBoolean, and direct each edge $i\to j$ whenever $i<j$..

Comment: How do I pick randomly from every column a "1" regularly

Comment: @dogukan, there should be a standard function for generating random numbers in whatever programming language you're using. I'm not sure why you want to pick something from each column. It's pairs of elements at $(i, j)$ and $(j, i)$ you need.